# Media queries catch tablet portrait

Tags: css

I have the following rules:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)

@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) /* Smartphones (landscape) */

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) /* Smartphones (portrait) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) /* tablets and desktops */
```

How to catch tablet portrait without affect the other rules?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard for "tablet portrait" in terms of device pixel width.

The @media `orientation` query is not very reliable at all and not widely supported.  [See here.](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/the_orientation.html)  You are best off just using `min-width` and `max-width` media queries and trying to get it to work at ALL possible widths than targeting a specific orientation.  That's pretty much how responsive design is supposed to work anyway.

Portrait mode tablets will generally be between 768px and ~960px wide.

Comment: Written on 9 April 2010

Comment: I know. It's still true, if not as emphatically so as it is put forth in the article.  Device orientation and change of orientation event (JS) are both still ludicrously hard to reliably detect in a safe/cross-device way.

Comment: Also, even if browser/device compatibility was 100% for the `orientation` media query my point about building sites to work at all possible widths would still be completely relevant.  IMO if you need to know the orientation and factor it into CSS it's much safer to detect it with JS and then add classes, etc as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation:portrait) and (min-height:1024px)
```

You should also beside specifying min-width and min-height specify max width and height combining it with orientation, then you really catch up mobiles without affecting others like tablets or pc, right now only with min-width for mobiles will also affect all devices accomplying that min-width

Answer (score 0):

[Pure CSS has helper classes](http://purecss.io/grids/#grid-helper-classes) for hiding stuff in tablets.

The media query it uses for tablets is as follows:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
```

You could also try adding `(orientation:portrait)` to that.

(As seen in http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure.css)